# Indicator LEDs to see which voltage rail is used to power the board

Tags: voltage, led, indicator

I have two voltage rails, 3.3V and 5V, that can be used to power the board, switchable by SPDT.
I am trying to provide two indicator LEDs so it is always obvious which rail is being used.

Probably simple, but can't figure it out.

[image]

Comment: Why not use a DPDT with the extra switch being used for the LEDs?

Comment: Indeed, why not. I feel so stupid now. It was the end of an intensive day and I was all over the electronics solutions instead. Thanks!

Comment: What about if I wanted to use a jumper on a 3-pin header instead of a switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not try to simulate. If there is a difference between output and 5V rail the Q1 opens and Q2 closes.
R5 serves to clamp voltage across D1R2 when Q1 is closed, otherwise D1 would be supplied a little through R4 and glow.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQhmQt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A neat solution - two transistors and three resistors. I've simulated and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to the original supply lines at the load side you can use this circuit.

The LED resistors R3 and R4 are calculated for 5 mA LED current.

Run a DC sweep to see the takeover short before 4 V. At this voltage both LEDs are on, which would result in yellow light if you use a common anode dual LED.

You may need to adjust R1 or R2 if you use a FET with a different threshold voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx5Z8z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

From comments.

> *Trying to provide two indicator LEDs so it is always obvious which
> rail is being used. Probably simple, but can't figure it out.*

Why not use a DPDT with the extra switch being used for the LEDs?

> *Indeed, why not. I feel so stupid now. It was the end of an intensive
> day and I was all over the electronics solutions instead. Thanks! –
> Robert Albi*

and

> *What about if I wanted to use a jumper on a 3-pin header instead of a
> switch? – Robert Albi*

That would require an electronic solution; use a comparator powered from the common power rail and set it to detect when the supply voltage was above (say) 4 volts. The output would go high and could illuminate an LED connected via a resistor to GND. When the output is low it would illuminate a different LED connected via a resistor to the common power rail.

Comment: Thought about that but (according to datasheet) a comparator can only have Vcc-1V on its inputs and if I power everything from a USB, 5V is all I have. Maybe 3 voltage dividers? To halve 2 rail voltages and make a reference of 2V?

Comment: You will need a voltage divider and a voltage reference @RobertAlbi ||| Besides, there are many comparators that have rail-to-rail inputs. You don't need them though.

Answer (score 1):

In response to Andy Aka comment:

> That would require an electronic solution; use a comparator powered
> from the common power rail and set it to detect when the supply
> voltage was above (say) 4 volts. The output would go high and could
> illuminate an LED connected via a resistor to GND. When the output is
> low it would illuminate a different LED connected via a resistor to
> the common power rail.

So, for the comparator I have available LM393, a dual open-collector comparator. And a solution could be:

[image]

Comment: 5V is present all the time?

Comment: Yes, it is present.

Answer (score 0):

## Diode circuit

### 5 V

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw3TwX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### 3.3 V

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3rp7U.png)</sup>

### Transistor circuit

### 5 V

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foSjQu.png)</sup>

### 3.3 V

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVzJco.png)</sup>